# model form is not saving in django it is telling user can not be nul

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i crated a model name address and connected with user by foreign key so a user can have multiple address but it is not saving i want form to take that user id to save but i don't how to do that

here is my models.py

```
class Address(models.Model):
    phoneNumberRegex = RegexValidator(regex = r"^\d{10,10}$")
    pincodeRegex = RegexValidator(regex = r"^\d{6,6}$")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='address')
    reciever_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    phone_no = models.CharField(validators = [phoneNumberRegex], max_length = 10, blank=False)
    alt_phone_no = models.CharField(validators = [phoneNumberRegex], max_length = 10, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=state_choice, blank=False)
    pincode = models.CharField(validators = [pincodeRegex], max_length = 6, blank=False)
    eighteen = models.CharField(blank=False, choices=eighteen_choice, default='Yes', max_length=4 )
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

my views.py

```
@login_required
def add_address(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Addressform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('accounts:home')
    else:
        form = Addressform()
    return render(request, 'add_address.html', {'form': form})
```

my form.py

```
class Addressform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user', 'joined_date', 'updated_at']
        labels = {
            'reciever_name':'Reciever Name',
            'phone_no':'Phone No',
            'alt_phone_no':'Alternate Phone No',
            'state':'State/Union Territory',
            'pincode':'Area Pincode',
            'eighteen':'Is reciever is 18+',
            'city':'City',
            'address':'Address',
            'locality':'Locality',
        }
        widgets = {
            'eighteen': forms.RadioSelect()
        }
```

what i want is in user field it take that user who his login automatically but i don't understand how i can achieve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are excluding the user field from the form, it gets a null value on the post request. With a foreign key you cannot have a null field in the database. You have 2 options:

**1) Add the request user**

```
    @login_required
def add_address(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Addressform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.user = request.user
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('accounts:home')
    else:
        form = Addressform()
    return render(request, 'add_address.html', {'form': form})
```

This will add the primary key of the user who is submitting the form as the foreign key of the address and hence associate the user with the address.

**2) Allow user to select the user to associate with the address (not suggested)**

The alternative method is to allow the user to select the user you want to associate with the address but it is not suggested as any user can associate any user with a particular address.

```
class Addressform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['joined_date', 'updated_at']
        labels = {
            'reciever_name':'Reciever Name',
            'phone_no':'Phone No',
            'alt_phone_no':'Alternate Phone No',
            'state':'State/Union Territory',
            'pincode':'Area Pincode',
            'eighteen':'Is reciever is 18+',
            'city':'City',
            'address':'Address',
            'locality':'Locality',
        }
        widgets = {
            'eighteen': forms.RadioSelect()
        }
```

Comment: yeah i totaly forgot that thing thank you and please remove commit=true in form save() otherwise it will throw error